# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() returns undefined in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the auth status after refreshing the app and previously signing in but `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` gives undefined. The motive behind this is to either navigate to home screen or signIn screen by using the auth status.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Spinner} from '../components/common';

class Switch extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const userData = this.checkUser();
    this.switchContent(userData);
  }
  checkUser = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (userData) => {
      return userData;
    });
  };
  switchContent(userData) {
    console.log(userData);
    if (userData) {
      return this.props.persistantSignIn();
    }
    return this.props.navigation.push('SignInForm');
  }
  renderComponent() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Spinner />
      </View>
  }
  render() {
    return <View style={{flex:1}}>{this.renderComponent()}</View>;
  }
}

export default connect(null, {persistantSignIn})(Switch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of `onAuthStateChanged` (i.e. `userData`) should be processed within the anonymous function. Also note that until a user is signed in, `userData` will be `null`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( (userData) => {
      this.switchContent(userData);
    });
  }
```

There is no need to wrap `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` within an anonymous function, unless, for example, you were to use `useEffect`, such as the following:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

...
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged( userData => {
      this.switchContent(userData);
    })
  },[])
```